# wpf treeview get selected value

Tags: wpf, treeview, datarowview

I have a `TreeView` and a `ListBox`.  Both of them get populated from different `DataTable`s.

The `Treeview` gets its data from:

```
 DataTable product_type = new DataTable();
 product_type.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_product_type", typeof(int)));
 product_type.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
 product_type.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_parent",typeof(int)));
 DS.Tables.Add(product_type);
```

The parent child relation:

```
DS.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("rsParentChild", product_type.Columns["id_product_type"], product_type.Columns["id_parent"]));
```

So I want to get **the id_product_type** from the TreeView on **SelectedItemChanged** and pass it to my listbox, but how do I get the actual value, the int?

Comment: can you provide the xaml so as to create a sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tht's what you are looking for(i used a dataview to bind the list) :

```
private void tlstView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            int new_value =(int)((DataRowView)e.NewValue).Row["id_product_type"];
        }
```